# Why does `var exports = module.exports = {};` works but not `let exports = module.exports = {};`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

During code optimisation of my project, I was replacing all instances of `var` keyword with `let` because I think there is no particular use left for `var`. I did a 'Find & Replace' in all files to do this.

In some custom modules I had used statements like:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
```

which worked fine.

Now, after replacing it with `let`, it became:

```
let exports = module.exports = {};
```

It does not work now and gives an error

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'exports' has already been declared

Though I can use `var` and avoid this problem, I still want to know what is the reason behind this.

**EDIT:** I have not used `let exports = <something>;` anywhere in same module file. So this is the only statement where I have declared `exports` variable.

Comment: Because you used `let exports = <something>` more than once within same scope.

Comment: @Mjh sorry but I do not understand how is that so.

Comment: the error is telling you it is already defined ... can't get much simpler than that

Comment: @C0dekid I know the basic difference between `let` and `var` which is `block scoping`. But I have not used `let exports = <something>` anywhere else in same custom module.

Comment: exports is already used by the `module.exports`. Change the name of your variable to something else then `exports.`

Comment: If your computer tells you that you **have** then you **have**. The problem that you need to solve is **where** you did that. That's all. It's really that simple in computer world, when you get an error such as that one, there's no `But I have not used` or `Stupid computer` etc. YOU made a mistake. Now you have to fix it. Quite honestly, I don't see what you got from doing the whole search/replace. It's  commendable that you want to *get it right*, but in this particular case - you simply broke everything and gave yourself more work. If you look for problems, you'll find them.

Comment: Also, if you still don't think you've used it twice - just look for `let exports` in your code and tell us how many occurrences you'll get.

Comment: @C0dekid you're right. It worked when I changed that particular statement to `let exportsObj = module.exports = {};`. I had not declared `exports` anywhere else, but I could not see that `module.exports` will clash with `exports`. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mjh Thanks for your help but it's not always the case. I had already searched the code to find another occurrence but it was not there and as @ C0dekid pointed out, the problem was in this same statement that I have posted here.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, I would suggest you read up on how require works and how internally module._load module._compile works to understand what's happening. This question directly relates to the how require works in node's.

require(): Loads an external module
require.resolve(): Resolves a module name to its absolute path;
require.main: The main module;
require.cache: All cached modules;
require.extensions: Available compilation methods for each valid file type, based on its extension;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because `exports` is already initialized in Nodejs module system.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

The object exists, `module.exports` when the module loads.  Since `let` is scope specific it is preventing you from limiting the scope.  `const` would also fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain some more why `var` does work if `exports` variable is already declared by the module system?

Comment: Because `var` doesn't care if something is already declared, but `let` does (mostly anyway).

Comment: So what's the fix?